# Spring (boot) property loading?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I really don't know how to do what I want 'out of the box', and I think it should be easy(?) ...
Use case :
In development, I have a set of properties which are required. These I should be able to specify in a file which is distributed in the jar. These are used/available to the @Value annotation (which I realise is another level, ...)
In (unit) test, I should be able to override these properties, using the same filename.
In production, I need to be able to gather the ones I want to override from an arbitrary location. When I run my application, I would like these to be merged, with (that sort of) priority order. Basic defaults can then be provided 'in jar', and then overridden by 'local'.
Is there a way to do this (whether in core spring or spring-boot)?
I'm really not looking for a workaround - I'm willing to do a tailored solution for my app - but I'd just like to make sure that I haven't missed an obvious solution
Thx

Comment: Have you read [Spring Boot's documentation on externalised configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config)?

Comment: I have read this thoroughly, thanks. It seems to work from the spring-boot pov - but the underlying spring configuration mechanism doesn't (seem to) work the same way. I am either missing something or it only does this for 'known' files/properties?

Comment: It works for application.properties and application.y(a)ml files

Comment: That's what I thought. Is there a way to use these files to initialise the spring configuration such that, when I try to add a PropertySource (using file or classpath notation) that it will automatically pick up other files - specifically I want to be able to pull in 'site' configuration files.